# Convert cardinal wind directions to degrees

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe like below with cardinal wind directions :

```
|  X       |
+----------+
|N         |
|NE        | 
|NNE       | 
|SSE       | 
|WSW       |
+----------+
```

Question is how can I convert the wind directions to degrees and store in a dataframe/excel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly create a dictionary:

```
d={'N':0, 'NNE':22.5,"NE":45,"ENE":67.5, 'E':90,'ESE':112.5, 'SE':135,'SSE':157.5, 'S':180,'SSW':202.5, 'SW':225,'WSW':247.5, 'W':270,'WNW':292.5,'NW':315,'NNW':337.5, 'N':0,'North':0,'East':90,'West':270,'South':180}
```

Finally use `strip()` method and `map()` method:

```
df['X']=df['X'].str.strip().map(d)
```

**OR**

use `strip()` and `replace()` method

```
df['X']=df['X'].str.strip().replace(d)
```

Output of `df`:

```
    X
0   0.0
1   45.0
2   22.5
3   157.5
4   247.5
```